# Creating Incompatible Number Subtypes

Tags: java, ada

In Ada, it is possible to create incompatible equivalent numeric types:

```
type Integer_1 is range 1 .. 10;
type Integer_2 is range 1 .. 10;
A : Integer_1 := 8;
B : Integer_2 := A; -- illegal!
```

This prevents accidental logical errors such as adding a temperature to a distance.

Is it possible to do something similar in Java? E.g.

```
class Temperature extends Double {}
class Distance extends Double {}
Temperature temp = 20.0;
Distance distance = temp; // Illegal!
```

**EDIT**

I've discovered an [unrelated question with a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938276/java-creating-a-pseudo-native-type). This uses annotations and a special processor on compile to issue warnings when such assignments occur. It seems like the most painless way to do this - no need for special classes with the development and execution penalties those would incur.

Comment: You'll have to create a wrapper class to enforce your constraints.

Comment: Also consider [tag:JScience], for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44407365/230513).

Answer (score 4):

It's not common to wrap objects for the reason you specified in Java. But it is possible.

Rather than using `extends Double` (which doesn't work because *Double* is final). You can instead use delegation.

```
public class Distance {
    private double distance;
    // constructor, getter, setter
}

public class Temperature {
    private double temp;
    // constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Then the following will generate a compile-time error.

```
Temperature temp = new Temperature(20.0);
Distance distance = temp; // Illegal!
```